# how to use paper-input type date on iOS?

Tags: ios, mobile-safari, polymer-1.0, paper-elements

I'm trying to use a simple `<paper-input type="date"> </ paper-input>`, but the field does not work on the iPhone browser, both in Chrome as Safari.